# Interect with tab bar when popover is open

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a UITabBarController with a number of view controller . If from one View Controller i present a PopoverController , the tab bar becomes inactive until i dismiss the popover . Is there a way to interact with the tab bar even if the popover is displayed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't done this myself but I think you want to use [this property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverController/passthroughViews)

Answer (score 0):

**No**, I think that **you can't interact** with the UITabBarController while displaying the UIPopoverController, because the it is added to a view that, hierarchically, is higher than the RootViewController where your UITabBarController is situaded.

Answer (score 0):

it is easy to use **NSNotification** for intract with uitabbarcontroller from popup view controllers